# Solve $y^{(4)}-2y^{(3)}+2y'-y=xe^x.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y^{(4)}-2y^{(3)}+2y'-y=xe^x.$

The characteristic equation is $(r-1)^3(r+1)\Rightarrow y_h=(C_1+C_2x+C_3x^2)e^x+C_4e^{-x}.$

The problem is the particular equation. Why doesn't it work with the ansatz

$$y=(ax+b)e^x?$$

I get

\begin{array}{lcl}
y        & = & e^x(ax+b) \\
y'       & = & e^x(a(x+1)+b)\\
y''      & = & e^x(a(x+2)+b)  \\
y^{(3)}  & = & e^x(a(x+3)+b)  \\
y^{(4)}  & = & e^x(a(x+4)+b)
\end{array}

Setting these in i get $$e^x[((a(x+4)+b))-2((a(x+3)+b))+2(e^x(a(x+1)+b))-(e^x(ax+b))] = e^x\cdot 0=0.$$

So this doesn't work. Is it because I already have corresponding powers of $x$
in the homogenous solution? How can i fix my ansatz?

Comment: Look at the homogeneous portion of the solution, it should tell you why your particular solution isn't working. Remember you need linear independence.

Comment: As @ultrainstinct says, your guess is actually part of the homogeneous solution already (as you found when you plugged it in).  The method you use to handle repeated roots of the characteristic polynomial also handles how to adjust your guess in this situation.

Comment: I have never managed to work ansatz into a sentence.

Comment: @copper.hat, now you have!

Comment: @LSpice: :-) ${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Solve step by step the equation $$(D-1)^3(D+1)y=xe^x$$ (where $D$ is differentiation operator) and there is no need to worry about guessing particular solution. Let $z=(D-1)^3y$ so that $$(D+1)z=xe^x$$ or $$D(e^xz) =xe^{2x}$$ or $$ze^x=\frac{xe^{2x}}{2}-\frac{e^{2x}}{4}+a$$ or $$z=\frac{xe^x} {2}-\frac{e^x}{4}+ae^{-x}$$ Next put $t=(D-1)^2y$ so that $$(D-1)t=z$$ or $$D(te^{-x})= ze^{-x} =\frac{x} {2}-\frac{1}{4}+ae^{-2x}$$ or $$t=e^x\left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{4}\right) -\frac{ae^{-x}}{2}+be^x$$ Since $a$ is arbitrary constant one can replace $-a/2$ by $a$ to get $$t=e^x\left(\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{4}\right)+ae^{-x}+be^x$$ Going further let $u=(D-1)y$ so that $$(D-1)u=t$$ or $$D(ue^{-x}) =te^{-x} =\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x}{4}+ae^{-2x}+b$$ or $$u=e^{x} \left(\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^2}{8}\right)-\frac{ae^{-x}}{2}+bxe^x+ce^x$$ Replacing $-a/2$ by $a$ we get $$u=e^x\left(\frac{x^3}{12}-\frac{x^2}{8}\right)+ae^{-x}+bxe^x+ce^x$$ and in similar manner solving the final equation $(D-1)y=u$ we get $$y=e^x\left(\frac{x^4}{48}-\frac{x^3}{24}\right)+ae^{-x}+bx^2e^x+cxe^x+de^x$$ which is the desired solution.

Comment: Does this method work generally? And what exactly is the differential operator? How do you go from $(D+1)z=xe^x$ to $D(e^xz)=xe^{2x}$? Does the notion $D(e^xz)$ mean "the first derivative of $e^xz$?

Comment: @Parseval : let's say that this is *the* method to solve linear differential equation with constant coefficients which involves no tricks and surprises. Everything is visible in the solution itself. And it works for any equation where you can factor the characteristic equation. $D^n$ is shorthand for $\frac{d^n} {dx^n} $.

Comment: @Parseval: the standard method to solve $(D+a) y=z$ is to multiply the equation by $e^{ax} $ to get $e^{ax} (D+a) y=ze^{ax} $ and note that $D(ye^{ax}) =e^{ax} (D+a) y$.

Answer (score 3):

The  particular solution is $$y*=\frac{1}{(D-1)^3(D+1)}xe^x=e^x\frac{1}{D^3(D+2)}x=e^x\frac{1}{2D^3(1+\frac{D}{2})}x=e^x\frac{1}{2D^3}(1-\frac{D}{2}+...)x$$
$$=e^x\frac{1}{2D^3}(x-\frac{1}{2})=e^x\frac{1}{2}\int{\int{\int{(x-\frac{1}{2})dx}dx}dx}=\frac{e^x}{2}(\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^3}{12})=e^x(\frac{x^4}{48}-\frac{x^3}{24})   $$

Comment: What are you doing? I don't really see what you are doing with the differential operators.

Answer (score 1):

You need $y_p=(ax^4+bx^3)e^x$. Any lower order turns $0$ in your ODE.

Your ansatz is already a homogeneous solution.

Answer (score 1):

try $$y_P=e^x(ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e)$$

Comment: No need for the $c x^2 + d x + e$ part ….

Answer (score 1):

$y=(ax+b)e^x$  is part of your solution to the homogeneous equation.It will not help with finding a particular solution. Multiply it by $x^3$ and substitute in your inhomogeneous equation to find a particular solution. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking when solving linear ODE

- your homogeneous equation has root $r$ with multiplicity $m$ .
- the full equation has a RHS of the form $P(x)e^{rx}$ with $P$ polynomial.

Then you need to search for a particular solution in the form $Q(x)e^{rx}$ with $Q$ polynomial and $$\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m$$

Although since the homogeneous solution will already have vanishing terms $(C_0+C_1x+\cdots+C_{m-1}x^{m-1})e^{rx}$, you can ignore them in the polynomial Q.